# Estimating gas costs for large batch of transactions

Tags: transactions, gas, gas-price, pending-transactions, batch

I noticed on [EthGasStation](https://ethgasstation.info) the following below the estimated gas prices:

> Note: Estimates not valid when multiple transactions are batched from the same address or for transactions sent to addresses with many (e.g. > 100) pending transactions

**How** are the estimates affected by having multiple transactions batched from the same address or to addresses with many pending transactions?  What parts of the estimate are invalid, in which direction (high/low/unknown), and why?

**What is a good way to estimate the costs associated with a batch of e.g. >100 transactions?**

(Also, is "batch" a technical term with specific meaning as applied to Ethereum transactions, or does this word carry just the common meaning, "a group or set, issued relatively close in time to each other"?)